# Getting numbers from ordered list

Tags: jquery

I have a sortable jquery list (essentially this: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/, but ordered instead of unordered). And in this list I display dynamic content. I want users to be able to switch the order of the items on the list, and then upon clicking submit, the changes in order will be put into my database.

I want the changes to be detected by jquery. When the ordered list number does not equal the id of the div within it, I want that to be detected, and then both numbers to be put into hidden input fields in the div, that are marked by name as being part of that div.

I think I know how to do everything here, except for getting the numbers of the items on the ordered list. How can I use jquery to get the numbers of the items on an ordered list?

Comment: So, [*show us*](http://jsfiddle.net/) (add code to the question) what you (think you) *know* how to do. And then we'll help you go further.

Comment: You can use .index() to find the li's position relative to it's siblings.

Comment: Okay, I'm working on it.

Comment: @DavidThomas http://jsfiddle.net/Xqbm2/ I can't seem to get the jquery sorting to work in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I use jquery to get the numbers of the items on an ordered list?

That's easy:

```
$('#yourList>li').length
```

`>` is the child selector; it selects all *direct* children (children exactly one level deeper than the parent).

If you already have a jQuery element for the list:

```
$yourList.find('>li').length
```

Comment: This makes me facepalm now. I've learned so much in these past couple months.